# Important identity for covariant derivatives involving extrinsic curvature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

How can I demonstrate this identity?
$$\nabla_a(K^{ab}-\lambda Kg^{ab})=\Gamma^b_{ac}(K^{ac}-\lambda K g^{ac})$$
where $\lambda$ is a parameter, $K_{ij}$ is extrinsic curvature in ADM formalism and $g_{ij}$ is 3-metric ($i,j=1,2,3$).

Comment: What is the definition of $K^{ab}$?

Comment: Moreover, do all the indices run from $1$ to $3$?

Comment: Extrinsic curvature.Yes, the indexes can be 1, 2 or 3.